# Get a CMake property recursively on dependent targets

Tags: android, cmake

I'm building an Android APK using CMake, and one thing we need to do when building the APK is specify the list of additional shared libraries to be included in the archive.  There is a CMake property named [ANDROID_NATIVE_LIB_DEPENDENCIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ANDROID_NATIVE_LIB_DEPENDENCIES.html) that appears to be intended for this purpose based on its description, but when I've tried using it, this property doesn't appear to be transitive so it doesn't propagate to dependent targets.  As a workaround I've instead been defining a global property in my top-level CMakeLists.txt and having each target append to that property so the full list of dependencies will be available when I reach the packaging step for my main executable

Top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
if (ANDROID)
    # There is a CMake target property named ANDROID_NATIVE_LIB_DEPENDENCIES that seems like it should be used for this purpose,
    # but it doesn't appear to be transitive so it won't propagate from dependencies, so we'll define a global property instead
    define_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY ANDROID_DEPENDENCIES BRIEF_DOCS "Android dependencies" FULL_DOCS "Additional shared library dependencies for the Android package")
endif()
```

CMakeLists.txt for a library dependency that needs to include an external shared lib:

```
if(ANDROID)
    set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY ANDROID_DEPENDENCIES ${ANDROID_LIB})
endif()
```

CMakeLists.txt for main application:

```
    get_property(ANDROID_DEPENDS GLOBAL PROPERTY ANDROID_DEPENDENCIES)
```

This works for now with a single top-level application target, but won't work later on if I have to create additional top-level targets that use a different set of dependencies.

I want to know if there is a cleaner way to do this and actually make use of the built-in CMake property for its intended purpose - is there a way from my main application target to read the value of that property from all of its dependencies - I know I could iterate over the list of targets that are passed to `target_link_libraries` but if the dependency is more than one level deep this won't work so I wanted to know if there was a way to recursively fetch all dependency targets of a top-level target.

Essentially, I want to know if there's a way to handle this situation:

```
MyApp - target_link_libraries(MyApp Lib1 Lib2)
  -- Lib1 - set_target_property(Lib1 ANDROID_NATIVE_LIB_DEPENDENCIES libNativeLib.so)
  -- Lib2 - target_link_libraries(Lib2 Lib3)
    -- Lib3 - set_target_property(Lib3 ANDROID_NATIVE_LIB_DEPENDENCIES libNativeLib2.so)
```

In this scenario, `MyApp` needs to know the value of `ANDROID_NATIVE_LIB_DEPENDENCIES` on all its dependency targets in order to include all the necessary shared libs in the APK, but since it only directly depends on `Lib1` and `Lib2`, it can't see the value of the property on `Lib3`, unless there is a way to get a recursive list of dependencies from a top level target which I don't know of

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ANDROID_NATIVE_LIB_DEPENDENCIES.html) you refer to, this target property is filled from `CMAKE_ANDROID_NATIVE_LIB_DEPENDENCIES` variable. So you can assign a value to the variable at the top level, and all created targets will have that value as the property's value. As for transitive propagation of the property, it seems that CMake developers don't think about such usage: As far as I understand, all properties initialized from `CMAKE_` variables are not intended to be transitive.

Comment: Yeah I saw that it could be set by that variable, but I was more interested in a way to specify dependencies inside the build.  For example, one of our internal libraries depends on OpenCV, and when I use the `find_package` command to locate the OpenCV dependency, I can also get the install location of its shared libraries, but then later on when my application links our internal library (which has the OpenCV dependency) I need it to also get those OpenCV shared libs in order to include them in the APK.  Ideally I'd like to do that via the properties on our internal library target

Comment: I could have every target populate this property for its immediate dependencies, and then read the property off every dependency at the top level, but if the dependencies are more than one level deep that won't work, so since the property itself isn't transitive, I'm just wondering if there's a way to recursively fetch a list of dependency targets from a top level target